# How to view other group members if i am a member of that group?

Tags: django

In my mobile app,i am trying to create a system which i can fetch other group members that are already member to groups i belong to.But i can only fetch myself,rather than them.How can i do it?

Note: I can fetch them from GroupViewSet that i am in,but i have to access to them in GroupMemberViewSet so if i am admin of that group i can patch the groupmember's membership.

**Models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser,PermissionsMixin):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    username =models.CharField(max_length=40,unique=True,default='undefinedusername')

class Group(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)

class GroupMember(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='groupmembers')
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='groupmembers_set')
    isadmin =  models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ismod =  models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**Views.py**

```
class GroupMemberViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = GroupMember.objects.all().order_by('-timestamp')
    serializer_class = GroupMemberSerializer
    filter_backends = [UserFilterBackend]
```

**Filters.py**

```
class UserFilterBackend(filters.BaseFilterBackend):
    
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        return queryset.filter(author=request.user)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the queryset with:

```
class SameGroupBackend(filters.BaseFilterBackend):
    
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        return queryset.exclude(
            pk=request.user.pk
        ).filter(
            groupmembers__group__groupmembers_set__author=request.user
        ).distinct()
```

This will retrieve all `User`s that have at least *one* group in common with the `request.user`. We `.exclude(pk=request.user.pk)` if we want to exclude the logged in user (you can omit that part if the logged in user should be included).

It might be more elegant to span a `ManyToManyField` between `Group` and `User` and then make queries with this many-to-many relation instead. This then looks like:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Group(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='groups',
        through='GroupMember'
    )
```

the [**`through=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) specifies that you use a model as junction table.

By using such `ManyToManyField`, we can simplify the filtering to:

```
class SameGroupBackend(filters.BaseFilterBackend):
    
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        return queryset.exclude(
            pk=request.user.pk
        ).filter(
            groups__users=request.user
        ).distinct()
```

Comment: `   pk=self.request.user.pk
AttributeError: 'SameGroupFilterBackend' object has no attribute 'request'`

Comment: @umarbeyoglu: I made a typo, it is `request.user`, not `self.request.user`.

Comment: I have checked it before, because you answered 2 of my other questions before and never used self.request.user. But request.user also gives me another issue:

`File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1540, in names_to_path
    "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'groupmembers' into field. Choices are: author, author_id, grp`

Comment: @umarbeyoglu: you should use the serializer for the `User`. If you do not want to do that, you should remove the `groupmembers__` from the `.filter(...)` part.

Comment: It is also strange that your model says `group`, but your fields mention `grp`.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't use `User` for the serializer,because i have to directly reach for GroupMember model. But removing `groupmembers__` directly solved the problem.Thanks a lot!

Comment: For further notice to the author of the answer and future readers, i used the first option that author of the answer showed, ManyToManyField option is not tried so i cannot answer for that but the first option works.